# PHP, How to return new element for array with function

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add a new element to an array using a function.
This is my code:

```
$test = [];
$test[] = getTest('test_key');

function getTest($key){
    return [$key => 'test_value'];
}
```

This is the result. A multidimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test_key] => test_value
        )

)
```

But it's going one level to deep for me :)
This is the desired result:

```
Array
(
    [test_key] => test_value

)
```

What part am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an array and you push it to the $test array you had, that's why it became a multidimensional array. you may consider changing the function name, but just do so:

```
$test = [];
getTest($test, 'test_key');

function getTest(&$array,$key){
    $array[$key] = 'test_value';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing a 'var_dump()' of the '$test' var results an empty var. the new updated array stays within the function. I guess making it global might work. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: Where do you place the var_dump? also, pay attention you've to pass the array by reference (see the getTest function signature), still doesn't work for you?

Comment: ^^^ Pay attention to `&`

Comment: @MyLibary var_dump() after the function. But,

Comment: @AbraCadaver, mehehehe thanks! I deleted it. Though "how did that came here? Did I make a typo?" hehe.
So bottom line it works perfectly! Thanks. What's it called the '&' so I can find more info on what it is and does?

Comment: Holy moly, I was doubting on posting this question. But this stuff is awesome. This will clean up so much of my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge arrays with `array_merge`.  Here merging your result with your original array.

```
<?php

function getTest($key){
    return [$key => 'stool'];
}

$test = ['foo'=>'food'];
$test = array_merge($test, getTest('bar'));
print_r($test);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => food
    [bar] => stool
)
```